# Is there a way to delete a raster using arcpy / ArcGIS 10.0?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy

I'm trying to find a way to delete a raster dataset (in any format) using arcpy. As it is now I have been writing custom functions for each file type (eg, delete directory and pyramids for grids, delete .tif, .tfw, ...etc for geotiffs).

Seem like this should be an obvious thing but I can't find it in the function list.

Comment: Try [raster cleanup](http://forums.esri.com/thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=181364)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Delete_management](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Delete/001700000052000000/) option?

> Permanently deletes data from disk. All types of geographic data
>   supported by ArcGIS, as well as toolboxes and workspaces (folders,
>   geodatabases), can be deleted. If the specified item is a workspace,
>   all contained items are also deleted.

Comment: Thanks looks like it does the job. Don't know how I missed it!